# Choose service type based on Enum value

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

I would like to create kind of Factory Pattern, but am struggling.

```
//OperationType is an Enum
public interface SettlementService<OperationType>{
    void settleOperation(Order order);
}
```

then I have 2 services that handle different operation types in different ways.

```
public class ClientSettlementService implements SettlementService<OperationType.CLIENT> {
    @Override
    public void settleOperation(Order order) {

    }
}

public class CustomerSettlementService implements SettlementService<OperationType.CUSTOMER> {
    @Override
    public void settleOperation(Order order) {

    }
}
```

Then in my settlement method I have:

```
switch (order.getOperationType()) {
case OperationType.CLIENT:
    //here ClientSettlementService is called
    settlementService.settleOperation(order);
    break;
case OperationType.CUSTOMER:
    //here CustomerSettlementService is called
    settlementService.settleOperation(order);
    break;
default:
    LOG.error("Unsupported operation type.");
}
```

The code obviously doesn't work, but hope you get the idea. How do I do that?

Comment: In your interface `SettlementService<OperationType>` where do you use the type bound?

Comment: I really don't. The type is only used to determine what service I'm gonna use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement the `SettlementService` using the factory pattern you don't need a generic type awareness in the `interface`.

```
public interface SettlementService {
    void settleOperation(Order order);
}
```

Further, it's implementing classes would look like following -

```
public class ClientSettlementService implements SettlementService {
    @Override
    public void settleOperation(Order order) {
        System.out.println("clients!!");
    }
}

public class CustomerSettlementService implements SettlementService {
    @Override
    public void settleOperation(Order order) {
        System.out.println("customers!!");
    }
}
```

The factory that you want to build would then look like the following based on the `OperationType` enum.

```
public class SettlementFactory {
    private SettlementService provideService(OperationType operationType) {
        switch (operationType) {
            case CLIENT:
                return new ClientSettlementService();
            case CUSTOMER:
                return new CustomerSettlementService();
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported operation type!");
        }
    }
}
```

You can then make use of this factory to settle a given `Order` as:

```
private void settleOrder(Order order) {
    SettlementFactory settlementFactory = new SettlementFactory();
    SettlementService settlementService = settlementFactory.provideService(order.getOperationType());
    settlementService.settleOperation(order);
}
```

---

If you find the Factory class as overhead by any chance and want to cut the service providing capability short to the same method where you make use of it, you can use a `Map` and handle the service provided such as:

```
private void settleOrder(Order order) {
    Map<OperationType, SettlementService> typeSettlementServiceMap =
            Map.of(OperationType.CLIENT, new ClientSettlementService(),
                    OperationType.CUSTOMER, new CustomerSettlementService());
    SettlementService settlementService = typeSettlementServiceMap.get(order.getOperationType());
    if (settlementService == null) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("..message..");
    settlementService.settleOperation(order);
}
```